# Checking if the data from an API endpoint has changed (from an Angular frontend)

Tags: angular, rest, frontend, api-design

For my Angular application I have to get data from an API. Right now I am loading the data into a service in order to provide the components with the data.

```
export class DataService{
  private dataSource = new Subject();
  currentData = this.dataSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.get('/api/v1/data').subscribe(data => {
      this.updateData(data);
    });
  }

  updateData(data) {
    this.dataSource.next(data);
  }
}
```

The API data changes every 5 minutes to show the latest data.
I am now trying to check the if the data on the endpoint has changed in order to fire a new `GET`.

---

My first idea was to make a `GET` every 5 minutes but then I realized that I will start on website load. This makes it not synchronized with the API.

I am not sure if WebSockets / server-side events would work since the API is on an external server with limited interactability besides reading it.

---

So is there really any other way or is the only option to just spam the API with requests and see if it changes?

---

**Edit**: maybe another endpoint with the timestamp of the latest update could be used. Then the frontend can check if it has the latest updates.

Even though this wouldn't really solve the problem it would at least reduce the amount of unnecessary data being send.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using **Observables** [Sourse](https://angular.io/guide/observables)

> Observables Observables provide support for passing messages between
>   publishers and subscribers in your application. Observables offer
>   significant benefits over other techniques for event handling,
>   asynchronous programming, and handling multiple values.
>
> Observables are declarative—that is, you define a function for
>   publishing values, but it is not executed until a consumer subscribes
>   to it. The subscribed consumer then receives notifications until the
>   function completes, or until they unsubscribe.

```
 private subscribeLiveData(): void {

    this.dataSubcribed = Observable.timer(5000)
      .subscribe(() => this.refreshLiveData());
  }
  private refreshLiveData(): void {
    this.postsSubscription = this._livedata.getTask().subscribe(

      (data: YourModle[]) => {
        this.yourmodaldata = data;

      },
      function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      },
      function () {
        console.log("done");
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: As far as I understand I can use an Observable when passing data inside my application. But can I use them to get data from an external source? How would I know the external data has changed in this scenario?

Answer (score -1):

U can put your's method in  DoCheck[Life Cycle Hook]in component When Value Changes Automatically DoCheck Will Call

Answer (score -1):

It seems like polling is the easiest option.
For now I will use a timed poll from the API and synchronize it via global time.

```
  getData() {
      this.http.get("/assets/data.json").subscribe(data => {
        this.updateData(data);
      });

      const timer = 5 * 60;
      setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(new Date());
          this.getData();
      }, timer * 1000);
  }
```

Maybe I will give REST hooks a try but this will happen later.